# Cliking to expand the TreeView executes the code inside the listener

Tags: java, javafx

I have a treeview inside my javaFx application. Selecting the treeitem for the first time (first click) executes the code inside the listener which is fine, but when I try to expand the treeitem (on the second click) to see the subitems agian the code inside the listner gets executed!

```
    treeView.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
            StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (TreeItem<String> item = (TreeItem<String>) treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); item != null; item = item.getParent()) {

                pathBuilder.insert(0, item.getValue());
                pathBuilder.insert(0, "/");
            }
            String path = pathBuilder.toString();
            populateImageView(path.substring(1) + "/");
        }
    });
```

The code inside the listener should not execute when I try to expand the treeitem. 
any idea please!

Comment: You'll still get a mouse event with a click count of `1` before you'll get the mouse event with a click count of `2`. If your goal is to populate an image view when the item is selected, why not observe the [selection model](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#selectionModelProperty) of the `TreeView`?

Comment: would you please show me some code?

Comment: `treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> { ... });`

Comment: perfect! Thanks Slaw!